# tinyMCE 3 and 4 on same page

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

How is it possible to run 2 editors, once tinymce 3 for legacy reason and tinymce 4 directly from cachefly? I got a lot JavaScript errors, for sure. But is there a "noConflict" like in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is nothing like that.

Comment: I tried to preserve the tinymce Object of the tinymce3, when the tinymce4 loads, but I got a lot of JavaScript errors. So I suppose, it would only be possible if I use iFrames or I would try the new ShadowDOM functionality https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/324149970.